# Problems sending messages to a server using TCP sockets

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to send messages to a server, but when I connect, the server immediately fails receiving the message. It seems that the server "does not wait" for the user to type the message. The server is supposed to remain in that while loop, forever waiting for clients and printing their messages.

I have no idea what's wrong.

Server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define PORT 4000
#define WORD_SIZE 256
#define USER_SOCKETS 2
#define MAX_USERS 10

int receiveMessage(int socket, char message[])
{
    int bytesReceived;
    while (1)
    {
        bytesReceived = recv(socket, message, WORD_SIZE, 0);
        if (bytesReceived < 0)
            return -1;

        if (bytesReceived == 0)
            return 0;

    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int serverSockfd;
    socklen_t clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

    if ((serverSockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        printf("Error creating the socket.\n");

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bzero(&(serv_addr.sin_zero), 8);

    if (bind(serverSockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error binding the socket..\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (listen(serverSockfd, 5) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error on listening.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int newSockfd;
    while (1) 
    {
        if (newSockfd = accept(serverSockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen) < 0)
        {
            printf("Error on accept a new client.\n");
            continue;
        }

        char username[WORD_SIZE];
        if (receiveMessage(newSockfd, username) < 0)
        {
            printf("Error receiving message.\n");
            close(newSockfd);
        }

        printf("Message: %s\n", username);
        close(newSockfd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <unistd.h>    
#include <string.h>   
#include <sys/types.h>    
#include <sys/socket.h>  
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <netdb.h>

#define PORT 4000

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int sockfd, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent * server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage %s hostname\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
        printf("ERROR opening socket\n");

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serv_addr.sin_addr = * ((struct in_addr * ) server -> h_addr);
    bzero( & (serv_addr.sin_zero), 8);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr * ) & serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        printf("ERROR connecting\n");

    printf("Enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer, 256);
    fgets(buffer, 256, stdin);

    /* write in the socket */
    n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0)
        printf("ERROR writing to socket\n");

    bzero(buffer, 256);

    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "fails receiving the message" - how do you know that? Print reasonable message on error, e.g. with `perror()`. Can you connect to the server and send data with another client, e.g. `socat`, `netcat` or `telnet`? Why `bzero(&(serv_addr.sin_zero), 8);`? You also can debug your connection with `wireshark` or `tcpdump`.

Comment: `newSockfd = accept(...) < 0` is definitely wrong (missing parens)

Comment: Client: You do not correctly and completely handle the result returned by write().  Printffing the buffer after you just zeroed it is pointless.

Comment: Server: once your code actually compiles, (when you fix your brackets), it will not work reliably because you do not understand TCP streaming.  If the first 'receiveMessage()' recv call does not load the entire message, the second call will overwrite the data loaded by the first.

Comment: ..and 'printf("Message: %s...' called on a char array that is not guaranteed NUL-terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
if (newSockfd = accept(serverSockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen) < 0)
```

will set `newSockfd` to `0` if `accept()` succeeds, rather than to the descriptor of the socket. This is because `<` has a higher precedence than `=`, so the compiler behaves as-if you had written this:

```
if (newSockfd = (accept(serverSockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen) < 0))
```

You need to write this instead:

```
if ((newSockfd = accept(serverSockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen)) < 0)
```

Comment: Or, split the assignment and comparison into separate statements so there is no confusion, eg: `newSockfd = accept(serverSockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen); if (newSockfd < 0)`