# Can't connect with my server on different PC using sockets TPC in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, connection

I'm working on a client / server program using sockets. The server just listen for connections and prints it's username. The client tries to find the server and sends it's username. When you run the client, you have to pass three arguments: Your username, the IP address and the port.

The program works fine on same computer, but when I try to connect on a different PC, it can't connect. After a while, it prints "Error connecting to host.".

I am doing something wrong?
Thanks!

*Edit: Just one more info. My desktop (server) is on tethed USB internet connection, provided from my smartphone. The client is on Wi-Fi.*

*Edit2: Now the desktop is on cable and the notebook (client) is on Wi-Fi. Internet conection is up on both devices. I still can't connect. Connection timeout is the error.*

**Edit3: Well, now I connected both devices on wired (same router) and I connected fine. Seems I have to send an email to IT department of my uni.**

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define PORT 4000
#define WORD_SIZE 256

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    pthread_t tid;
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent * server;

    if (argc != 4) 
    {
        printf("Not enough arguments, please inform:\n");
        printf("<username> <server_ip_adress> <port>");
        return -1;
    }

    char username[WORD_SIZE], server_ip[WORD_SIZE], port[WORD_SIZE];
    strcpy(username, argv[1]);
    strcpy(server_ip, argv[2]);
    strcpy(port, argv[3]);


    server = gethostbyname(server_ip);
    if (server == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Error: no such host\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
    {
        printf("Error opening socket\n");
        return -1;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serv_addr.sin_addr = * ((struct in_addr * ) server->h_addr);
    bzero( & (serv_addr.sin_zero), 8);

    int status = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr * ) & serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    if (status < 0) 
    {
        printf("Error connecting to host.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (send(sockfd, username, WORD_SIZE, 0) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error sending username.\n");
        close(sockfd);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Username sent.\n");
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT 4000
#define WORD_SIZE 256

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int serverSockfd;
    socklen_t clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

    if ((serverSockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        printf("Error creating the socket.\n");

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(serverSockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error binding the socket.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (listen(serverSockfd, 5) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error on listening.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int newSockfd;
    while (1) 
    {
        newSockfd = accept(serverSockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);
        if (newSockfd < 0)
        {
            printf("Error on accept a new client.\n");
            continue;
        }

        char username[WORD_SIZE];
        if (recv(newSockfd, username, WORD_SIZE, 0) < 0)
        {
            printf("Error receiving username.\n");
            close(newSockfd);
            continue;
        }

        printf("User %s logged in.\n", username);
        close(newSockfd);
    }
}
```

Comment: When `connect` fails, you need to print the value of `errno`, and perhaps a translated string as well. Like `printf("Error connecting: %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno))`

Comment: ...or use `perror()` as an alternative.

Comment: For error reporting better use `perror` instead of `printf`, e.g. `perror("gethostbyname");` or `perror("sending username");` Using `perror` was already suggestede for your [recent related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75455259/10622916) BTW: `send` and `recv` normally return a positive number that indicates the number of bytes sent or received which might be less that the number you wanted to send/receive. You might have to repeat the call to send/receive the remaining bytes.

Comment: I get Error connecting: 110 - Connection timed out

Comment: I updated my original post with one more information. Might be useful.

Comment: Is the server machine and program up and running? Do you have a reachable network  between the client and the server? Do you have any firewalls in between? Can you ping one system from the other?

Comment: The server is up on the machine. Tried to connect with client from other. I can't ping my server from my notebook (100% packet loss). I disable the firewall in the server machine with `sudo systemctl stop firewalld`. Still can't connect.

Comment: Well, now I connected both devices on wired (same router) and I connected fine. Seems I have to send an email to IT department of my uni.

Comment: According to your last encounter, this would seem obvious that your question is actually related to network routing and network address translation port rediection. I would recommend researching what kind of firewall you are using to determine the requirements you need to give your server access.

Comment: If you are trying to access your server from the internet, you need to configure a DNAT rule in your gateway's firewall.